# Appending the validated User id into the Request header (Cookie) in DataPower

Tags: xslt, cookies, xslt-1.0, setcookie, ibm-datapower

I want append to Username into Cookie , so that the backend team will fetc the username from cookie.
So i tried to use the below code , but it dint append

```
<dp:append-http-request-header name = "'Cookie'" value = "concat('SM_USER=',$UserID) "/>
```

Where UserID contains value of username.

Is it right or anything else need to be added?

Comment: Can any one please update

Answer (score 1):

Take out the `http-`.  The extension element name is `dp:append-request-header`.

It's one of those odd inconsistencies in DataPower extension naming.  (They have been trying to deprecate the http-specific extension element names for some time now.)